# Python Appending arguments with slice notation

Tags: python, arguments, append, parameter-passing, slice

Hello I am trying to append the contents of system arguments 2 - however many entered to argument 1, here is my code

```
for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    doc = open(arg, "r")
data2 = doc.read()
doc.close()

tu = open(sys.argv[1], "a")
tu.write(data2)
tu.close()
```

entering 3 files however only adds file #3 to the end of file #1, shouldn't slice [2:] account for all arguments and not only the last one?

Comment: Are you aware that the only line that's actually inside the loop is `doc = open(arg, "r")`? Everything after that is outside the loop.

Comment: you should open `sys.argv[1]`at the beginning, and close at the end.

Comment: indentions are very important in Python - and this is your problem, not slicing.

Comment: Thank you all for the input, the placement of more lines into the loop actually did not make a difference. i will be sure to be more diligent with my formatting in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data2=""
for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    doc = open(arg, "r")
    data2 =data2+ doc.read()
    doc.close()

tu = open(sys.argv[1], "a")
tu.write(data2)
tu.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never thought of using + in this instance, despite past use for other means.